# Synonym For Locating When Context Is Not Geographical Location

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

So I am writing a research paper where we are predicting the *location* of a user's mobile device, the *location* being *Pocket*, *Hand* etc. Now, whenever I read my paper title I feel that locating is a misleading term as it somehow gives the image of *Geographical Location* and not what my research is about. So I would like to swap this term with something more relevant, yet my knowledge fails me to find such a word.

Any ideas? My tentative paper title is: *Locating Mobile Devices Accurately Using...*

Comment: Honestly, this might be an impossible task. Try rephrasing it to talk about *How a user holds their device* etc.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I am starting to think that this is indeed a impossible task :(

Comment: There are a lot of synonyms for *locate* that might work--just off the top of my head, *pinpoint* seems like a possibility. It might be more productive for you to look through some Thesaurus entries yourself, though, rather than us tossing possibilities at you.

Comment: 'location about the person'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This paper by Miluzzo, et al](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjiz7PombXPAhVkVWMKHezYAwoQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmiluzzo.info%2Fpubs%2Fmiluzzo-phonesense10.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEngmUuZb5pYu12Mo7K44yCTwXgew&bvm=bv.134052249,d.cGc&cad=rja). speaks of the "low-level *context*" of the mobile device:

> We believe efficiently computing the low level context of the phone,
>   that is, the position of the phone carried by a person (e.g., in the
>   pocket, in the hand, inside a backpack, on the hip, arm mounted, etc.)
>   in relation to the event being sensed -- which we call the phone
>   sensing context -- is a fundamental building block for new distributed
>   sensing applications built on mobile phones.

[This paper from Ubicomp](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjiz7PombXPAhVkVWMKHezYAwoQFgglMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ubicomp.org%2Fubicomp2013%2Fadjunct%2Fadjunct%2Fp31.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH1XWdyQXuyq397Nrt-KXu_ky1enQ) uses the word *placements*, as well as *placement contexts*:

> In this demonstration paper, we show a novel approach to detect the
>   common placements of a mobile phone, such as “in pocket”, “in bag” or
>   “out of pocket or bag”, from embedded proximity (IR) and light
>   sensors. We use sensor data fusion and pattern recognition to extract
>   distinct features from sensor signals and classify the boundaries
>   among these three phone placement contexts.

You can follow suit, e.g. *Accurately Determining Mobile Device Placement Contexts Using...*

Comment: *Placement* would be my choice too.

Comment: And how many people would understand this! It seems one step away from DIY jargon (and internet examples seem ill-defined also).

Answer (score -2):

Consider "Placing" or "Orienting". It could be even more clear if you used "Handheld" instead of or in addition to "Mobile" (to prime the mind to think about if the device is in your hands, a pocket, a backpack, on a table).

Or add "in Space" or "Spatial" to qualify the location as not being geography.

Comment: **Placing** sounds more like *putting* and **orienting** is a completely different thing. *Spacial* data is usually used in reference to Geography.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey True. I had the same feeling when I read the comment!